# Здравствуйте, пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы объекты по цепочке выполняли одну и ту же анимацию, подскажите пожалуйста, что для этого нужно?

Tags: unity3d, animator

Дело в том, что когда я включаю игру и нажимаю на клавишу у меня срабатывает эта анимация сразу на всех объектах. По объектам я иду циклом, видимо , через цикл передаются сразу всё объекты. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать, как сделать проигрывание анимации последовательным для списка объектов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Используй корутину которая будет с задержкой воспроизводить анимацию на каждом отдельном обьекте